# Rails: Failing Minitest - Action Correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, minitest, guard

So I have an app which I have written tests for including both 'Valid' and 'Invalid' user log in and user sign up.

All of the 'Invalid' tests are working fine but the valid tests are producing errors listed below despite the application correctly creating new users logging in users and rendering the correct views.

I wonder if anyone could point out whether the problem is in my tests or in some other area as I am struggling to find the problem.

ERRORS reported in 'Minitest'

> ERROR["test_valid_signup_information", UserSignupTest, 2.1755039319996285]
>    test_valid_signup_information#UserSignupTest (2.18s)
>   ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>               app/views/users/app.html.erb:138:in`block in _app_views_users_app_html_erb__2494824291632638359_70266943530800'
>               app/views/users/app.html.erb:137:in `_app_views_users_app_html_erb__2494824291632638359_70266943530800'
>               test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:25:in`block in '
>
> ERROR["test_valid_signup_information", UsersLoginTest, 4.1316103730005125]
>    test_valid_signup_information#UsersLoginTest (4.13s)
>   ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>               app/views/users/app.html.erb:138:in`block in _app_views_users_app_html_erb__2494824291632638359_70266916015300'
>               app/views/users/app.html.erb:137:in `_app_views_users_app_html_erb__2494824291632638359_70266916015300'
>               test/integration/users_login_test.rb:47:in`block in '
>
> ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 4.260822469999766]
>    test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (4.26s)
>   ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>               app/views/users/app.html.erb:138:in`block in _app_views_users_app_html_erb__2494824291632638359_70266953255400'
>               app/views/users/app.html.erb:137:in `_app_views_users_app_html_erb__2494824291632638359_70266953255400'
>               test/integration/users_login_test.rb:25:in`block in '

Tests producing ERRORS

```
test "valid signup information" do
get signup_path
assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
post signup_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                     email: "user@example.org",
                                     password:              "password",
                                     password_confirmation: "password" } }
end
follow_redirect!
assert_template '/app'
    assert_not flash.empty?
end
end

test "valid signup information" do
get signup_path
assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                     email: "user@example.com",
                                     password:              "password",
                                     password_confirmation: "password" } }
end
follow_redirect!
assert_template 'users/app'
assert is_logged_in?
end

test "login with valid information" do
get login_path
post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email,
                                      password: 'password' } }
assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to app_path
follow_redirect!
assert_template 'users/app'
assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    delete logout_path
assert_not is_logged_in?
assert_redirected_to root_url
    delete logout_path
follow_redirect!
assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
end
```

Routes:

```
get '/app', to: 'users#app'
get '/users', to: 'users#index'
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
```

View where error is generated: /users/app.html.erb 137-138

```
136  <tbody>
137     <% @projects.each do |project| %>
138     <% if project.user.name == current_user.name %>
         <tr>
            <td id="hidden">
                <%= project.id %>
            </td>
            <td class="ellipsis">
                <%= link_to project.name, project_path(project) %>
            </td>
            <td class="ellipsis" id="hidden">
                <%= project.description %>
            </td>
            <td class= "centre">
                <%= project.user.name %>
            </td>
          </tr>
            <% elsif current_user.admin?%>
          <tr>
            <td id="hidden">
              <%= project.id %>
            </td>
            <td class="ellipsis">
              <%= link_to project.name, project_path(project) %>
            </td>
            <td class="ellipsis" id="hidden">
              <%= project.description %>
            </td>
            <td class= "centre">
              <%= project.user.name %>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Obviously if I need to post more information please let me know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Has your test `project` object a user associated?, if not, there's the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, i"m pretty new to this... I don't understand what you're asking. Could you explain what you mean further. I have test users entered and they work fine in other tests

Comment: Your `app.html.erb` file checks `project.user.name == current_user.name`, if by any chance, there's no user for that project, then you couldn't access the "name from the user from the project". So you need to check on your test, are you creating the projects and their relationships?

Comment: I see, yes, its not possible to create a project without having first created a user account and then all new projects are assigned the user i.d of the creator. I am able to call projects by user id in other areas, like users project index, so that relationship is working fine... in fact the function this test is testing for is actually ok... it isn't broken, only the test fails